# JQuery mousedown issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, gamequery

What I am trying to achieve is changing the way a player moves in a JQuery game.
Rather than a keypress I am trying to get the player to move if they click/mousedown on text, with id "left".

Original code is as follows.

```
            if(jQuery.gameQuery.keyTracker[65]){ //this is left! (a)
                var nextpos = parseInt($("#player").css("left"))-5;
                if(nextpos > 0){
                    $("#player").css("left", ""+nextpos+"px");
                }
            }
```

My code is as follows, and when I play, it just continuously moves the player left without me pressing anything. It shouldn't move left until I click or mousedown on the "left" id text.

```
            if ($('#left').mousedown){
                var nextpos = parseInt($("#player").css("left"))-5;
                if(nextpos > 0){
                    $("#player").css("left", ""+nextpos+"px");
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
if ($('#left').mousedown){
```

will always be true. You're checking if `$()` has a `mousedown` property and it always will because all jQuery objects have a `mousedown` method. You probably want to bind a mousedown event handler:

```
$('#left').mousedown(function(e) {
    //...
});
```

Comment: Thank you!! One thing, now it doesn't move smoothly with easing, it moves across jaggedly. It also doesn't continuously move if I hold the mouse down on the #left?

Comment: @MartinH23: Hard to say what's up without a functional example.

Comment: @MartinH23: That's a bit more than an example.

Comment: Sorry, that's the complete code- just thought something else may require editing. Any idea what I can do to make it smoother?